# Give importance to word proximity rather than word count in the documents with Apache Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

I am working on rails application and which is based on Apache Solr search engine and we are using Sunspot gem. But I am facing one problem, If I search query `source of source` then its giving me thousands of results by using `and` result. But I feel first 5 results are not more relevant after 5 th result the results are relevant. The first 5 results contains only source word many times but my 6th result contains exact query `i.e source of source` so I want to give importance to documents which contains exactly my query text then other. I also tried with boost and also boosted the document, but not getting the proper result. Can anyone help me to find a way to give more importance to documents which contains exact my query rather than the documents which contains more word source, of, source?

My schema.xml contains following code

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;\(\)]+"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<!-- *** This fieldType is generated for exact match boosting *** -->
<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help is appriciatted

Comment: whats the fieldtype used for the this search field?

Comment: have you tried "source source"~2 ?

Comment: Did you try to add [Keyword Repeat Filter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory) ?

Comment: @alexf Is Keyword Repeat Filter applicable for exact field or text field? Please see the my schema.xml file I have just added the code in above question, can you let me know

Comment: To really boost this, you can add this filter to both of them !

Comment: @alexf I had added Keyword Repeat Filter in schema.xml file but at solr end it gave error as a `Failed to load KeywordRepeatFilter` and also tried with `KeywordRepeatFilterFactory` but its gave same error

Comment: @alexf if I search a `341 ITR 1`  text in full text but in the top its giving irrelevant results, but I have only 21 documents which has above string and that documents are no coming in top, I have given more boost to exact fields, do you know how to get first 21 results on top than others ?